# How to split data with commas expect for ones in double quotes

Tags: python

If I have maybe

```
data = something1, something2, "1,111", "222", "33,333", something3
```

And want to split it to

```
['something1', 'something2', '"1,111"', '"222"', '"33,333"', 'something3']
```

How would I be able to do this?

I have tried using the .split(",") but it does not handle the quotations.
Also have went through using regex as well as csv reader module but wasn't able to get the wanted results :(.

Sorry if this is a really basic question.

Answer (score 2):

Hi if you have a space after coma then you can split it using split(", ") instead of just splitting at , like below:

```
# program
data = 'something1, something2, "1,111", "222", "33,333", something3'
data1 = data.split(", ")
print(data1)
```